# Postman REST API: Compare two XML response

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to compare XML reponse of 2 REST API's. I wanted to compare few fields from Response1 to Response2.

Response1:

```
<d:site_name>Bondi Junction</d:site_name>
<d:country>AU</d:country>
<d:regio>NSW</d:regio>
<d:contact>123456789</d:contact>
```

Response2:

```
<d:country>AU</d:country>
<d:region>NSW</d:region>
```

I have created a Collection which will have both API's and I wanna run both API's and compare the available columns ( I don't want to compare completely).

Could you please guide me an approach to done.

Thanks,
Sekar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gr6T.jpg)

Comment: Try this [XmlXdiff](https://pypi.org/project/XmlXdiff/) python library. But attention it is currently under development. Here is an [example diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR8c8.png) concerning your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to compare values of xml attributes and elements without converting the xml to json.

Below is a working example(xml converted to json) for 2 use-cases (test)

1. Using the function `difference()`, you can test if the 2 xmls have any differences.
2. Using json path to extract the value of xml elements you can also compare specific field values

   ```
   function difference(object, base) {
       function changes(object, base) {
           return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
               if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
                   result[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value;
               }
           });
       }
       return changes(object, base);
   }


   var xml1 = `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
              <envelope>
               <body>
                   <d:site_name>Bondi Junction</d:site_name>
                   <d:country>AU</d:country>
                   <d:regio>NSW</d:regio>
                   <d:contact>123456789</d:contact>
               </body>
              </envelope>
   `;
   var xml2 = `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
               <envelope>
                <body>
                   <d:country>AU</d:country>
                   <d:region>NSW</d:region>
                </body>
              </envelope>
   `;

   var jsonObject1 = xml2Json(xml1);
   var jsonObject2 = xml2Json(xml2);
   var diff = difference(jsonObject1, jsonObject2);

   console.log(diff);

   pm.test("Test for any differences in the 2 payloads", function() {
       //diff object will be empty in case of no differences
       pm.expect(_.isEmpty(diff)).to.eql(true);

   });


   pm.test("Test for the value of country in 2 payloads ", function() {
       pm.expect(jsonObject1.envelope.body.country).to.eql(jsonObject2.envelope.body.country);
   });
   ```